# How do I implement a button, that checks if the fields in a document are not empty? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function

I want to write a JavaScript function, that checks if the fields in the following HTML document are not empty. I do not want a prompt for every information but instead I want to implement a button at the end, that checks every field and returns a message that tells you which fields are still not filled.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stylesheet.css">
    <title>Student erfassen</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="../index.html">Übersicht Studenten</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    <h3>Student erfassen</h3>

    <table>
        <tr>
          <td><form>Vorname:</td>
          <td><p></form>
            <label for="Vorname">
              <input id="Vorname" name="Vorname">
            </label>
        </p></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><form>Nachname:</td>
            <td><p><form>
              <label for="Nachname">
                <input id="Nachname" name="Nachname">
              </label>
          </p></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td><form>Geburtsdatum:</td>
            <td><p><form>
              <label for="geburtsdatum">
                <input id="geburtsdatum" name="geburtsdatum">
              </label>
          </p></td>
           </tr>

           <tr>
            <td><form id="fakultät" method="POST">
        Fakultät: </td>
        <td><select name="fakultät" size="1">
        <option>01</option>
        <option>02</option>
        <option>03</option>
        <option>04</option>
        <option>05</option>
        <option>06</option>
        <option>07</option>
        <option>08</option>
        <option>09</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
        </select>
        </form>
    </td>
    </tr>

           <tr>
            <td><form>Studiengruppe:</td>
            <td><p><form>
              <label for="studiengruppe">
                <input id="studiengruppe" name="studiengruppe">
              </label>
          </p></td>
           </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><form method="POST">
    Semester: </td>
    <td><select id="semester" name="Semester" size="1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    </select>
    </form>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>email:</td>
  <td><p><form>
    <label for="email">
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
    </label>
</p></td></tr>
<tr><td>_____________________________</td></tr>
<tr><td>Ich biete mich als Tutor an für:</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><form>Modul 1</td>
    <td><p><form>
      <label for="modul1">
        <input id="modul1" name="modul1">
      </label>
  </p></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><form>Modul 2</td>
      <td><p><form>
        <label for="modul2">
          <input id="modul2" name="modul2">
        </label>
    </p></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><form>Modul 3</td>
      <td><p><form>
        <label for="modul3">
          <input id="modul3" name="modul3">
        </label>
    </p></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
Validierung

<script src="./student _erfassen.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I started to create variables to read the content of the fields but have an error message already

> ("Expression expected") in line 4

```
<script>

funtion validate() {
    var vorname = document.getElementById("vorname").value;
    var nachname = document.getElementById("nachname").value;
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Just remove all spaces from input values. If nothing remains then they are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
var nameInput = document.getElementById("name");
var surnameInput = document.getElementById("surname");
//others fields

function checkEmptyInputs(){
var fields = [nameInput, surnameInput];
var emptyFields = fields.filter(x => x.value == "" || x.value == undefined);
var emptyFieldsIds = emptyFields.map(x => x.id);

return emptyFields.length > 0 ? alert(`There are empty fields with Ids: ${emptyFieldsIds.join(',')}`) : alert(`There are not empty fields`)
}
```

```html
<html>
  <form>
    <input id="name" value="John" type="text"/>
    <input id="surname" value="Doe" type="text"/>
  </form>
  <button onClick="checkEmptyInputs()">check fields</button>
</html>
```

Comment: but arent you putting the values for the name and surname already into the variable instead of getting it from the user input?

Comment: I'm setting a *default value*, but ```nameInput``` and ```surnameInput``` ```.value``` property will hold the value of the user input. try my example and check out how when you change the value of the input, the nameInput.value changes too

Comment: im still getting the same error message in your implementation in the checkEmptyInputs function. It also has some problems with your compare operator at x>= value   "Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'>'}` or `&gt;`?ts(1382)"

Comment: I'm not writing ">=" in any of my code, I do have => that stands for an arrow function. Please provide your implementation to see how I can help you

Comment: `<script>


var nameInput = document.getElementById("name");
var surnameInput = document.getElementById("surname");
var birthdayInput = document.getElementById("birthday");
var semesterInput = document.getElementById("semester");
var emailInput = document.getElementById("email");

function checkEmptyInputs(){
var fields = [nameInput, surnameInput];
var emptyFields = fields.filter(x => x.value == "" || x.value == undefined);

return emptyFields.length > 0 ? alert('There are empty fields') : alert('There are no empty fields')
}
</script>`

Comment: The code provided above works it's ok. Check three things: 1. As per the code above, you are not closing the </script> tag. 2. You are defining ```birthdayInput```, ```facultyInput``` and ```semesterInput``` but not using them inside the function. 3. Check the error that you specify earlier: ```unexpected value..``` in the console of your site, next to this message should be numbers like (30, 50) those are the line count and the column count of where your code fails, check that the failure happens in the implementation of that function or somewhere else

Comment: it works, thanks. i had some typos in my .js file. I also want to give the exact fields that are not filled back to the user instead of only the info if there are unfilled fields. How can i do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224299/discussion-between-rod-ramirez-and-nikva).